# Trignometry and Greatest Integer function analysis question .

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry

Q) If $\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3}$ are three distinct values lying in $[0,3\pi)$ for which $\tan \theta =\frac{7}{10}$ then $$\left[\tan\frac{\theta_{1}}{3}\tan \frac{\theta_{2}}{3}+\tan\frac{\theta_{2}}{3}\tan \frac{\theta_{3}}{3}+\tan\frac{\theta_{3}}{3}\tan \frac{\theta_{1}}{3}\right]$$ is =___ (where $[.]$ denotes G.I.F) ?

**My Attempts**

My basic analysis was that $$0<\theta_{1}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$  $$\pi<\theta_{2}<\frac{3\pi}{2}$$ $$2\pi<\theta_{1}<\frac{5\pi}{2}$$ (I *might* be wrong here)

Multiplied by $\frac{1}{3}$ and applied $\tan$ on LHS and RHS .

$$0<\tan\frac{\theta_{1}}{3}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$  $$\sqrt{3}<\tan\frac{\theta_{2}}{3}<\infty$$ $$-\sqrt{3}<\tan\frac{\theta_{1}}{3}<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Now we know that $\tan$ has fundamental period $\pi$ so we have

$$\theta_{1}$$ $$\theta_{2}=\pi+\theta_{1}$$ $$\theta_{3}=2\pi+\theta_{1}$$

Now if my procedure so far is accurate how do i use this to effectively solve the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Use $\tan3A=\dfrac{3\tan A-\tan^3A}{1-3\tan^2A}$ in $\dfrac7{10}=\tan\theta$ to form a Cubic equation in $\tan\dfrac\theta3$

Now use Vieta's formula

Comment: @SujithZis, Could you form the cubic equation suggested? Then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example

Comment: Okay that was a huge calculation but i solved for the roots and i got $-1.124,0.206,3.017$ now how do i disqualify the other two roots because options are a)3 b)-3 c)2 d)-2

Comment: @SujithZis, DO we really need to solve the cubic to find $$\sum\tan\dfrac{\theta_1}3\tan\dfrac{\theta_2}3$$

Comment: so we have use the summation of roots formula but why is it that $\tan\dfrac{\theta_1}3\tan\dfrac{\theta_2}3$ is a sub product of the root of the cubic polynomial $$\tan^{3}\dfrac{\theta}3-\frac{21}{10} \tan^{2}\dfrac{\theta}3 -3 \tan\dfrac{\theta}3 +\frac{7}{10}=0$$ ?

Comment: Okay i understood it now so final answer is $-3$ right ?

Comment: @SujithZis, So it should be

Comment: okay , but some thing doesn't smell right we haven't made any use of GIF [.] here

Comment: And also i found one contradiction too when we solve the cubic equation I'm getting roots as $1.12,0.2,3.01$ plugging those values into the question I'm getting $3,0,27$ as the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30139/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-sujith-zis).